# How to refactor common Jenkins JobDSL code?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the following JobDSL spec:

```
job {
  steps {
    gradle('generateLock saveLock', '-PdependencyLock.includeTransitives=true', true) { node ->
      node / wrapperScript('${NEBULA_HOME}/gradlew')
    }
    gradle('check', '', true) { node ->
      node / wrapperScript('${NEBULA_HOME}/gradlew')
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to refactor the common code, say, into a function:

```
def gradlew(String tasks, String options) {
  gradle(tasks, options, true) { node ->
    node / wrapperScript('${NEBULA_HOME}/gradlew')
  }
}
```

But the `gradle` function isn't visible from within the `gradlew` function. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The curly brackets form a Groovy closure. Each closure has a delegate object to which method calls are directed. And the delegate can be accessed via the [delegate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#getDelegate()) property. You can pass that delegate to the helper function to get access to it's methods.

```
def gradlew(def context, String tasks, String options = '') {
  context.gradle(tasks, options, true) { node ->
    node / wrapperScript('${NEBULA_HOME}/gradlew')
  }
}
job {
  steps {
    gradlew(delegate, 'generateLock saveLock', '-PdependencyLock.includeTransitives=true')
    gradlew(delegate, 'check')
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend doing some explicit examples on the project wiki on how to extract commonly used code. We were searching for the same thing for quite some time.

Comment: I'm going to update the Job DSL wiki page about configure blocks, see https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/683

Comment: What does the forward slash do after node -> node / ... ?

Comment: @daspilker it took me about 3 hours of searching to finally stumble across this answer and realize that i needed the delegate property.  I had been using "this".  Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: I'd now like to refactor a lot of commmon code into a helper class.  But 'Process Job DSLs' finds my helper class alongside my JobDSL class and tries to run it as a JobDSL.  How to overcome this?