# Groovy delegates working as intended?

Tags: groovy

I have a short snippet where I try to delegate the variable resolution to the delegate. However the delegates value isnt used, instead the owners value is used. Is this intentional or is this a bug?

```
class Person {
    int age
}

def age = -5
def closure = { -> age }
closure.delegate = new Person(age: 99)
closure.resolveStrategy == Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY

assert closure.call() == 99
```

Above code fails, with the closure returning -5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code returns `-5` because the variable `age` is defined withing the lexical scope of the closure, meaning that the closure can use the value of the variable `age`.

You have to explicitly tell the closure to use the age property of the delegate:

```
def closure = { -> delegate.age }
```

Try the following code:

```
class Person {
    int age
}  
def age = -5 
def closure = { -> delegate.age * age } 
closure.delegate = new Person(age: 99)
closure.resolveStrategy == Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY 
assert closure.call() == 99*-5
```

Comment: So delegation ONLY comes into play when the variable cant be found in the owner scope?

Comment: if you mean that the resolution of a variable without "delegate." within the closure will be resolved first through the lexical scope of the closure and then (if set) though the delegate, then yes. In fact, if the variable is not defined in the lexical scope and no delegate is set, a MissingPropertyException is thrown. A useful resource you may want to have a look to is the Groovy Language page about Closures (section 3.2.4): http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy_2

Comment: Yes, what I meant is, that the lexical scope to the closure ist the scope of the owner. 
 I read the documentation, but it didnt make this point very clear. I didnt really get the lexical scope of a closure, and that delegates are only used when the property isnt found in-scope. Thanks for clearing that up!